# k-means method clarification

Tags: r, clustering, k-means

I am pretty new to k-means and cluster analysis methods, but I am trying to do it on 5 different measures of inequality and redistribution (Gini, P90/P10, Atkinson with different parameters and the percentage of redistribution defined as difference between Gini pre and post social transfers) to check how the 15 countries I have are grouped based on these measures. I am referring to the 4 Welfare regimes defined in literature, so using k=4 as exogenous information and applying the k-means method for clustering.

However, using R in both kmeans command and eclust command from factorextra package the first argument is a matrix and/or a data frame. What is the difference if I use an Euclidean distance matrix as input? 
For example, what's the mathematical/computational difference between using the following:

```
hc8<-subset(wave_8, select = c(Gini.Pareto, P90.P10.Pareto, Atkinson.1, Atkinson.2, percent))
hc8 <- scale(hc8)

res.kmean8<-eclust(hc8, "kmeans", k=4, hc_method="ward.D2")
```

and using, instead,

```
res.kmean8<-eclust(dist(hc8)^2, "kmeans", k=4, hc_method="ward.D2")
```

Thank you for the help and clarification

Answer (score 0):

Kmeans cannot use a distance matrix.

In order to compte means, it *needs* to have vector data.

If you pass a distance matrix, it will treat the rows as vectors and compute averages of these distances, and squared errors there. This adds hard to understand bias.

The method is just *very* designed to squared Euclidean.

If you want to use a distance matrix, use PAM (k-medoids) instead. If you want to minimize Euclidean distances, PAM *can* find better solutions than k-means (but does not necessarily so, because it is constrained to use data points as centers).

Comment: Sorry to bother again, but so, the main differences between the two approach in terms of R coding is that k-means within the eclust function is internally computing the Euclidean distances to create the clusters, whereas the PAM works as well if you use a distance matrix as input? Thanks

Comment: See the documentation of the functions for the input requirements.